# CameraRemoteAPI get number of remaing pictures to take

Tags: camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm developing an Android app with CameraRemoteApi to take pictures using an HDR-AS30V and store them on the smartphone. I need to know if it's possible to get the number of pictures the camera microSD can hold before it's full.

Answer (score 1):

'getStorageInformation' API can be used to determine number of recordable images and also recordable time left. Right now only HDR-AZ1 and Lens style cameras QX1 and DSC-QX30 support this API.
Please check the latest SDK documentation for more information on the API.

Best Regards,
Prem, Developer World team